# How can I get a 2D cross-section of a 3D object using a shader?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, shader

I have an idea for a 2D game that uses 3D models that are cut at the center of the Z axis. However, I have found no way to properly get just the intersection to show.

Culling the front and back of the camera to be extremely thin leaves a small outline of the model, since there's no way for it to render the inside. I could use ray marching, but it would limit me to primitive objects and seems a little overkill for what I need. I've found a lot of cross-section shaders online, but they require the back of the camera to not be culled.

Below is a visual example of what I need (demonstrated with Blender's boolean tool rather than a shader), any help is appreciated as I've been looking for a way to do this for months.

[Before Intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZXRx.png) vs [After Intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzc2u.png)

Comment: You could make the shader render the backface and override the normal direction, so that it appears to be flat inside.